# Can I use an earlier version of testnet?

Tags: testnet

I am looking to mine bitcoins with ease. But, first, I want to know how can I access an earlier testnet (testnet2). I have future plans to do this. I need to know how to open it up on the command line and I will take it from there.

Comment: Why do you need testnet2? It's practically the same as testnet3. If you just want a network that you can basically have full control over, use regtest.

Comment: It has a lower difficulty.

Comment: So? Regtest has basically no difficulty, you can mine there. Also, testnet3's difficulty is easily gamed down to be the minimum difficulty.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the long term?